# How to recursively immutify a data type passed by parameter in one method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, methods, types

I'm trying to solve a practice exercise where I need to immutify data types recursively, but I have problems with the recursive case:

> The function returns an immutable equivalent data structure (one that could be used for
>   values in a set or keys in a dict). The types int, str, and frozenset are already immutable. Convert a
>   set to a frozenset; convert all the values in a tuple to be their immutable equivalents, in the same
>   order); convert a list to a tuple (with immutable equivalents of its values, in the same order); convert a
>   dict to tuple of 2-tuples

I got to the base case, but not much else...

```
def immutify(a : 'an int, str, list, tuple, set, or dict') -> 'an int, str, tuple, or forzenset':
    if (isinstance(a, int)):
        return a
    if (isinstance(a, str)):
        return a
    if (isinstance(a, tuple)):
        # immutify each element in it?
    if (isinstance(a, frozenset)):
        # immutify each element in it?
    if (isinstance(a, set)):
        # return an immutified frozenset of a?
    if (isinstance(a, list)):
         # return an immutified tuple of a?
    if (isinstance(a, dict)):
        #return an immutified tuple of a?
```

The expected output is:

```
immutify(1) # -->1
immutify('a') # -->'a'
immutify( (1, 2, 3)) # -->(1, 2, 3)
immutify( frozenset([1, 2, 3])) # -->frozenset({1, 2, 3})
immutify( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) # -->(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
immutify( [1, 2, [3, [4], 5], 6])# -->(1, 2, (3, (4,), 5), 6)
immutify( [1, 2, (3, [4], 5), 6]) # -->(1, 2, (3, (4,), 5), 6)
immutify( [{1,2}, {3,frozenset([4,5])}, {6,7}]) #-->(frozenset({1, 2}), frozenset({3, frozenset({4, 5})}), frozenset({6, 7}))
immutify( [{1,2}, {3,frozenset([4,5])}, [{5,6}]]) #-->(frozenset({1, 2}), frozenset({3, frozenset({4, 5})}), (frozenset({5, 6}),))
immutify( {'b' : [1,2], 'a' : {'ab': {1,2}, 'aa' : (1,2)}}) #-->(('a', (('aa', (1, 2)), ('ab', frozenset({1, 2})))), ('b', (1, 2)))
```

EDIT: I almost got there:

```
def immutify(a : 'an int, str, list, tuple, set, or dict') -> 'an int, str, tuple, or forzenset':
    if (isinstance(a, int)):
        return a
    if (isinstance(a, str)):
        return a
    if (isinstance(a, tuple)):
        out = []
        for elem in a:
            new = immutify(elem)
            out.append(new)
        return tuple(out)
    if (isinstance(a, frozenset)):
        out = []
        for elem in a:
            new = immutify(elem)
            out.append(new)
        return frozenset(out)
    if (isinstance(a, set)):
        out = []
        for elem in a:
            new = immutify(elem)
            out.append(new)
        return tuple(out)

    if (isinstance(a, list)):
        out = []
        for elem in a:
            new = immutify(elem)
            out.append(new)
        return tuple(out)
    if (isinstance(a, dict)):
        out = []
        for elem in a:
            new = immutify(elem)
            out.append(new)
        return tuple(out)
```

Comment: There is no attempt for recursion in your code. Please [edit] your question and include what you have tried.

Comment: I didn't know how to even format it. That's part of the question.

Comment: Maybe start with implementing basic recursion. Just visit every member down the tree and print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

```
def immutify(a : 'an int, str, list, tuple, set, or dict') -> 'an int, str, tuple, or forzenset':
    if (isinstance(a, int)):
        return a
    if (isinstance(a, str)):
        return a
    if (isinstance(a, tuple)):
        out = []
        for elem in a:
            new = immutify(elem)
            out.append(new)
        return tuple(out)
    if (isinstance(a, frozenset)):
        #out = []
        #for elem in a:
            #new = immutify(elem)
            #out.append(new)
        #return frozenset(out)
        return a
    if (isinstance(a, set)):
        out = []
        for elem in a:
            new = immutify(elem)
            out.append(new)
        return frozenset(out)

    if (isinstance(a, list)):
        out = []
        for elem in a:
            new = immutify(elem)
            out.append(new)
        return tuple(out)
    if (isinstance(a, dict)):
        tup = []
        pair = []
        for elem in a:
            new1 = immutify(elem)
            new2 = immutify(a[elem])
            pair.append(new1)
            pair.append(new2)
            tup.append(tuple(pair))
            pair = []
        return tuple(tup)
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer for newer versions of Python.

```py
from typing import Any, Sequence, Mapping

# Since typing.Hashable doesn't check recursively you actually
# have to try hashing it.
def is_hashable(obj):
    try:
        hash(obj)
        return True
    except:
        return False

def to_hashable(obj: Any):
    # So that we don't infinitely recurse since frozenset and tuples
    # are Sequences.
    if is_hashable(obj):
        return obj
    elif isinstance(obj, Mapping):
        return frozenset([(to_hashable(k), to_hashable(v)) for k, v in obj.items()])
    elif isinstance(obj, Sequence):
        return frozenset([to_hashable(i) for i in obj])
    else:
        raise ValueError("Object is not hashable")

to_hashable({1: 2, 3: [4, 5]})  # frozenset({(1, 2), (3, frozenset({4, 5}))})
```

Two things of note, there is a `Hashable` class but it's not as useful as you might initially assume which is why you have to actually try hashing the object.

```py
isinstance(({}, {}), Hashable) # == True
hash(({}, {})) # raises ValueError
```

The second is that at the time of writing there isn't a class that means "iterable that isn't string" which is *by far* the most common needed case. However, since strings are hashable we don't have to worry about it here. Just something to be aware of if you modify this code.

Link to the relevant docs. The values in `typing` are aliases to the classes in `collections.abc` but are more often used.

- [`collections.abc.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence)
- [`collections.abc.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping)
- [`collections.abc.Hashable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Hashable)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).